# Exceptions in WPF Word Addin are not being handled

Tags: wpf, exception, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I am creating a WPF Office add in, and I would like to handle all exceptions in one place. To do this I use the following code in the constructor of my MainWindowViewModel:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter += new 
     DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventHandler(HandleAllException);
```

In my test environment I host the WPF app from a console application project, and exceptions are handled as expected. When I host the WPF app from within word however, nothing happens when exceptions are thrown. There is no notification at all that there has even been an exception, other than in the output window in visual studio. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What are the exceptions in the VS output window? This won't catch `COMExceptions` - only WPF managed exceptions.

Comment: The message in the output window is "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Bw.SharePoint.Client.dll but was not handled in user code." In my test environment this goes straight to my handler method as expected so I am confused as to why it does not when launching the app from within Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing the way in which I launch my WPF app. I believe the problem was related to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/05/12/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application.aspx).